# Trasfer properties from API responses in SOAPUI

Tags: json, soap, soapui

First of all, I read official documents and read other threads on here but I'm having trouble figuring this issue out. So please help me out :)

Now, 
I have ONE soapUI project and under that I have two different test suites. 
I create an account using one test suite (generate account API) and in JSON response I get an access token back.

there are bunch of APIs in the second test suite and all of this APIs use access token from first suite.

So what I essentially want to do is, save token from first suite and use it as a variable (or any other way) in the second suite for all subsequent API calls. Is it possible?

[Transfer JSON properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq8Ns.png)

pay load looks like following

```json
{
   "accountName": "Ya-mmy",
   "userEmail": "yashxcgdtuyihxfaap7@gmail.com",
   "send_invitation_email": true,
}
```

Response looks like following

```json
{
   "primary_user_email": "yashxcgdtuyihxfaap7@gmail.com",
   "access_token": "8cfe0670-897c-46d0-b0f6-c74519624ebf",
   "tenant_name": "Ya-mmy"
}
```

Comment: can you provide any more information ? / code?

Comment: @javapapo Added payload and response

Comment: @user5754867, the question is only **is it possible**, then yes. Get the response value and set the access token at project level so, it can be accessed easily anywhere in the project.

Comment: @Rao No, I actually would like to know what I am doing wrong. I posted a pic that shows what I currently have

Comment: @user5754867, ok add my answer below, try it out.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by multiple ways

1. adding a *groovy script* test step after the *rest request* step where you are currently getting access token.
2. without using additional step, just use *script assertion* for the *rest request* step where you are getting access token. this way, you can even check that there is some value you received in the response.

Its again personal choice, and I prefer and providing here #2 way.

Add the below script in the **script assertion** for your rest request step:

```groovy
import net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper
def jsonResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.responseContent)
assert null != jsonResponse.access_token, "access_token of response either does not have value or null"
context.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('ACCESS_TOKEN', jsonResponse.access_token)
```

Now, you can use `${#Project#ACCESS_TOKEN}` where ever you need the access token in your *testSuite*

Answer (score 1):

I just solved similar problem using build in property transfer feature.

In the source, put "Response" as a Property and "JSONPath" as a language.
In the blank field add: `$access_token` in your case.

Then just point to right target. It can be TestSuite or Global custom properties. You have to specify the name of custom property first, e.g. "access_token". It will be saved there.

Now, to use it anywhere in your tests, simply use: `${#TestSuite#access_token}` or accordingly if you saved it as a Global property.

Answer (score 0):

Without groovy also we can store this in property and use that property across the test Steps:

Steps Required for this:

1. Add a Property Transfer step after Rest request
2. Add a properties step and a property "SecurityToken" with empty value

**In Property Transfer add new Transfer "TransferSecurityToken"**

**source: Select REST(Request)  and In**  **Property Select ResponseAsXml**

- Internally your JSON Respose will converted to XML.

Use xpath like **//*:access_token** in source and

in **target Select Properties   -- > SecurityToken**

Now property SecurityToken have the Response value of 1 API response "access_token"

use ${Properties#SecurityToken}in your request

---

Additionally you can directly use following statement in other Test Request **${FirstTeststepName#ResponseAsXml#//*:acess_token}**

Hope these two solution Helps

Comment: I believe that one can't do `xpath` on `json` response.

Comment: On the second instance aslo, it is unknown `FirstTestStepName` because that step is entirely in different test suite. I am afraid that it works.

Comment: @Rao Your belief is wrong. Note the "Response**AsXml**" in the answer above.

Comment: @SiKing, as per the question, getting the token is in different test suite and utilizing access_token` in different testsuite. So, IMO, it will not be able to identify the above mentioned property expansion.

Comment: More over  some REST methods support only `json` format, no xml support.

Comment: @ Rao, in Property Transfer Step ResponseAsXml convert Json  to:  [<Response xmlns="***">    <primary_user_email>yashxcgdtuyihxfaap7@gmail.com</primary_user_email>   
   <access_token>8cfe0670-897c-46d0-b0f6-c74519624ebf</access_token>      
   <tenant_name>Ya-mmy</tenant_name>   
</Response>]     and user can do xpath can help Here

Comment: @Rao, In Property Transfer we can have Target Property as Global, Project or Testsuite based also, so you can transfer "accessToken" value to these property also .(Siiking is right) . ResponseAsXml  method convert the  Json Response to xml so no need to worry for -----Rest method only support Json from my point of view.

Comment: @TestHat, I could not get it working like what you say. Find the [screen shots](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01175342144604479920) for the steps followed and noticing error. Could not get away with it.

Comment: @TestHat it actually did transfer the property. I selected my testsuite as target but I'm not able to retrieve it in the next testcase

Comment: @user5754867 : Tried for POST it worked [check the Doc](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=47131365509646137551)

Comment: @user5754867: Get Request worked fine with ${#TestSuite#Outproperty}, Let know your rest request content snap [Get Example](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02276710174070725691)

Comment: @TestHat-- so I was able to transfer properties and use it in the same suite but it doesn't work for two seperate suite.

Comment: @user5754867 : Please create a project property if you want to transferred the properties between test suites. If you want to share the content at child (say Test cases level); go one level up that is parent (parent of Test cases - Test Suite).